# Struts2 Action Regular Expression/Wild card for URL

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to Struts2 but so far I have made decent progress using the API. However, I am stuck at something which I need to get out from. I am using Struts2 with Spring integration. I am writing my Action classes with annotation as like many of you I love annotations.

My requirement is that URLs will be in the following nature:

```
http://<DOMAIN>/program/program1.jspx
http://<DOMAIN>/program/program2.jspx
http://<DOMAIN>/program/program3.jspx
```

As you can see there is a certain pattern in the URL with program1, program2 and program3 varying and the rest are all static. I have very easily handled similar situation with Spring MVC (I don't have the option of using Spring MVC for the current project) like `"/program/{program_name}.jspx"` in my other project.

But when I use the same in struts2 I get the error. My Action class is as follows:

```
@Result(name="program", location="program", type="tiles")
public class ProgramAction extends ActionSupport {

   @Action("program/{programName}")
   public String getProgramPage() {
     // few more lines of code  
     return "program";      
  }
}
```

The error is

```
2013-02-28 15:46:35.591 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-3] CommonsLogger.java:60 
Could not find action or result
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name program1.
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189) ~[xwork-core-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61) ~[struts2-core-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39) ~[struts2-core-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58) ~[xwork-core-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:475) ~[struts2-core-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
....
....
```

My `struts.xml` file is as follows:

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="jspx" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default, json-default, rest-default" namespace="/">       
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
    </result-types>
</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slash in your action name. struts by default does not like this to correct that add:

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Quaternion!! Your answer helped me to resolve the issue. I really appreciate your help. Sorry if my question was too elementary.

Comment: No problem, it's an easy mistake. Look into the conventions plugin, if you haven't already.

Comment: Also if this helped resolve the issue, and the issue is now fully resolved. Make the answer as "accepted" the green check mark. Also please do this for any other resolved questions you might have, SO rewards you with 2 rep, each time you find your answer. Not a bad deal.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you defined the action annotation on method. Try `<s:a namespace="/" action="program/program1" method="programPage" />` in the JSP.

Comment: Hi Roman, the JSP comes into the picture only when the Action class completes and forwards the request to the JSP. So I am not sure whether I am following your intructions.

Comment: I know, you are not mastering JSP right? Put it into JSP and browse to it, then open page in the source view and look at the rendered HTML. Sure you can easily find link with the anchor tag. Look at the href attribute you'll see how should you call your action.

Comment: I did that in other JSP and I got the following <a href="/program/program1!programPage.jspx;jsessionid=01A6D22B4245C19B272168B97C170CC3"></a>. However when I call http://<DOMAIN>/program/program1!programPage.jspx I still get the same error!